My python program with multiprocess and multithreading will never stop
I have 6 processes, and each of them will be consumer, and 1 process for producer. the producer will read the file path to a multiprocess queue. and the consumer will have two threads: one to read the file from process_queue and put the data to the thread_queue, and one thread will do the calculation and put the result to result_queue(which is a process. queue).  The problem is that I find every worker process will reach the end, but the program will stuck at the worker.join() in the main thread, I don’t know why, I am so confused.
Below is my code
Cores = 8
def main():
    start_time = time.perf_counter()

    process_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    result_q = multiprocessing.Queue()

    gather_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_file_path, args=(process_q,))
    gather_process.start()

    worker_process = []
    for i in range(Cores - 2):
        worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=mul_heatmap_worker, args=(process_q,result_q))
        worker.start()
        worker_process.append(worker)
        
        print(f"process start{worker}")

    print("all process started")
    gather_process.join()
    print("gather is done")

    for i in range(Cores - 2):
        print("before sending None to process")
        process_q.put(None)
        print("sending None to process")

    #process_q.close()
    #process_q.join_thread()
    #result_q
    for i in range(Cores - 2):
        print(i)
        worker = worker_process[i]
        worker.join()
        print("one process is done")

    

    print("all process is done")
    mask_shape = (1024 + 1, 2048 + 1)
    total_mask = np.zeros(mask_shape)
    while not result_q.empty():
        total_mask += result_q.get().get_HeatMape_plt()
    #HM.finalize()
    #one_heatmap()
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    duration = end_time - start_time
    
    #print(f"the Total bbox are {total_pds_bbox}")
    print(f"the duration of the execution is {duration}")
    #print(f"time = {execution_time}")
    #to_Array(df,["person", "rider"])

def get_file_path(iner_process_q):
    total_files = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(Cityscapes_Fine_GT_Path):
        global total_json_read
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith('json'):
                total_files += 1
                file_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                
                iner_process_q.put(file_path)

    print("gather is done in method")
    


'''Two thread are using for Cityscapes dataset evaluation'''
def mul_heatmap_worker(iner_process_q, iner_result_q):
    #current 46 sec with I/O thread

    thread_q = Queue()
    
    io_thread = threading.Thread(target=read_json_files_to_df, args=(iner_process_q,thread_q))
    print("io start")
    io_thread.start()

    print("processing")
    process_thread = threading.Thread(target=sta_Cityscapes, args=(iner_result_q,thread_q))
    process_thread.start()

    #converter_thread = threading.Thread(target=HM.convert_to_gpu)
    #converter_thread.start()

    io_thread.join()
    print("io is done")
    thread_q.put(None)
    process_thread.join()
    print("processing is done")

    #HM.show_HeatMape_plt()
    #print(total_json_read)


'''Thread for reading the json file to a DataFrame and puting it to json queue, save I/O time'''
def read_json_files_to_df(iner_process_q, iner_thread_q):
    while True:

        #get from main queue
        
        file_path = iner_process_q.get()
        
        if file_path is None:
            break

        df = pd.read_json(file_path)
        iner_thread_q.put(df)
        #total_json_read += 1

def sta_Cityscapes(iner_result_q,iner_thread_q):

    HM_for_worker = HeatMaper(width=2048, height=1024)
    while True:
        df = iner_thread_q.get()
        #global total_pds_bbox
        #The last one in the queue will be None
        if df is None:
            print("read the None")
            break
        pds = findPedstrain(df, ["person", "rider"])
        
        if pds.size > 0:
            pdlocations = pds['objects'].apply(lambda x :  x['polygon'])
            
            for alist in pdlocations:
                points = np.array(alist)
                HM_for_worker.add_to_mask(points)
                #total_pds_bbox += 1

    iner_result_q.put(HM_for_worker)
    print("puting HM")


Try updating python and see if it will help, also you are not handling exceptions, if any exception is thrown you will deadlock
